# Managing a Git workflow with multiple developers making large changes to XML configuration files

Tags: git

Our team of developers (about 10-12 people) are working with a set of tools which make changes to a set of shared XML configuration files in our project. These XML files are used by the tools to configure and auto-generate a large chunk of our software stack. We are experiencing significant Git workflow issues while working with these tools due to the following factors:

- Some of the XML configuration files are common to the project and get changed virtually every time anyone makes a change to our configuration.
- Some of the changes our configuration tools make to the shared XML files are very large, often on the order of thousands or tens of thousands of lines.
- Several developers are independently making their own changes to the XML configuration files. These changes often conflict with the changes of other developers.
- We are using a code review tool which requires each commit to obtain approvals from several other people before it can be merged into our master branch.
- Once a change has been merged, all conflicting changes must be rebased.

Because of these factors, our ability to work in parallel as a team has been significantly impeded. We experience a lot of merge conflicts as we are working because the changes to the common XML files are often so large. We spend a lot of time performing multiple rebases as changes are merged to master. Sometimes the merge conflict resolutions are so complicated that we're forced to redo our changes using the configuration tool. All in all, we're spending a lot of time doing what feels like unnecessary busywork.

Does anyone have any recommendations for strategies for coping with this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these XML files more like content than source code?

Comment: They're closer to source code. Specifically, they're what the tool uses to generate the source code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with `Some of the changes our configuration tools make to the shared XML files are very large, often on the order of thousands or tens of thousands of lines.`? Where do these xml files come from?

Comment: How often are they changed? Why?

Comment: Sounds like you should break up the files into pieces that can be concatenated or use an include mechanism of some sort to reduce the size, localize changes, and separate things to reduce collisions.

Comment: @eftshift0 To answer your question, we purchase a large codebase from a 3rd party as our basic software stack, goes all the way down to the microcontroller hardware itself. We are responsible for writing the application layer above this basic software. This codebase is parameterized and can be configured for the user's requirements. The XML files represent the user-selectable parts of this basic software stack and come with the third-party software delivery. Custom tools from the same 3rd party manipulate the XML files and autogenerate the C code for our basic software from the configuration.

Comment: So.... you code on top of files that are generated from a previous build phase?

Answer (score 0):

> [We] are working with a set of tools which make changes to a set of shared XML configuration files [...] Some [...] get changed virtually every time anyone makes a change to our configuration [...] Some of the changes our configuration tools make [...] are very large, often on the order of thousands or tens of thousands of lines.

Your tools are treating these configs like media files. Literally, "between" files, "middle layer" files, your tools are treating them as media files because that's what they are.  And they act like other media files: not intended for human consumption. Source code is intended for human consumption. Your configs are not.

With some unknown amount of luck you'll be able to massage or translate the xml contents so small changes made in the tool are reflected by small changes made in the configs, and any two people making the same change have a good chance of producing  recognizably similar ones in the configs—in short, make a source-code rendition of whatever your tools are trying to work with, and track that. In a perfect world you'd be able to fix your existing tool to work with that format directly.

But if you don't have that kind of luck, you're kind of stuck.  All vcs's are built to presume the extent and nature and location of changes are reflected in the source. No vcs works with compiler object files for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

First I will give you advice for your particular workflow and how to integrate a few git tactics that may help.

1. Rebase often. Your developers should frequently update the main branch and rebase their feature branches against it to ensure that they are dealing with merge conflicts as a flow rather than all at once.
2. Learn about the rerere argument for merging and in general. This will help simplify some of the big merges that occur.

Beyond that, I would recommend looking into some other tools that feature code gen such as UML modeling suites (EA, etc) that will allow you to have a more comprehensive and understandable workflow. XML files are a headache and a half.